# Error trying to create a keychain "UNIX[No such file or directory]

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, keychain

I am trying to automate a process and i need to create a keychain. This process runs as a celery task under the _www user (OS Yosemite).

I get the following error:

```
security create-keychain -p mypassword keychain_test.keychain
security: SecKeychainCreate keychain_test.keychain: UNIX[No such file or directory]
```

I've been looking at what could cause this specific error message but no luck so far. Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keychain data is usually stored in a `Library/Keychains` directory under a user's home directory. The `_www` user on Mac OS X does not have a "real" home directory with a writable `Library` subdirectory, so it has nowhere to store a keychain.

You will need to run this task as another user.